# Specified cast is not valid while processing fieldreader

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

The specified cast not valid occurs when I try to get the fieldreader to datatype int.

`_userid` is of `int` type in database

```
var _fieldReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (_fieldReader.Read())
{
      _userId = _fieldReader.GetInt16(0);
}
sqlCon.Close();
```

Can anyone please help me with the issue?

Comment: Use `GetInt32` not `GetInt16`.

Comment: `GetInt16` is saying "I expect this to be a 16-bit integer"; if it *isn't*, then: don't use that; if it is actually an `int`, use `GetInt32`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user_id is int type in your database it match with a  32bits integer. Use `GetInt32()` instead :

```
 _userId = _fieldReader.GetInt32(0);
```